# Unexpected Exception While updating DataGridView : " Index was outside the bounds of the array" even if index is proper

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

I am trying to update DataGridView. While updating it throws exception randomly.(Not every time).

```
 foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGrdVwReport.Rows)
 {
       try
      {   
          f_RowIndex = row.Index;
          f_ColCount = row.Cells.Count;
          row.Cells[2].Value = p_Count;  //Exception here
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
          m_objLogFile.Error(CLASS_NAME + "->" + METHOD_NAME + "() : inner foreach : " + "f_RowIndex = " + f_RowIndex);
          m_objLogFile.Error(CLASS_NAME + "->" + METHOD_NAME + "() : inner foreach : " + "f_ColCount = " + f_ColCount);
          m_objLogFile.Error(CLASS_NAME + "->" + METHOD_NAME + "() : inner foreach : " + "p_Count= " + p_Count);
          m_objLogFile.Error(CLASS_NAME + "->" + METHOD_NAME + "() : inner foreach : " + ex.Message);
      }
```

Exception is:

> Index was outside the bounds of the array.

Stacktrace is:

> at System.Windows.Forms.PropertyStore.GetObject(Int32 key, Boolean& found)
>   at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellStyle.set_SelectionBackColor(Color value)
>      at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCell.GetInheritedStyle(DataGridViewCellStyle inheritedCellStyle, Int32 rowIndex, Boolean includeColors)
>   at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCell.GetPreferredHeight(Int32 rowIndex, Int32 width)
>   at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewRow.GetPreferredHeight(Int32 rowIndex, DataGridViewAutoSizeRowMode autoSizeRowMode, Boolean fixedWidth)
>   at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.AutoResizeRowInternal(Int32 rowIndex, DataGridViewAutoSizeRowMode autoSizeRowMode, Boolean fixedWidth, Boolean internalAutosizing)
>   at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.OnCellCommonChange(Int32 columnIndex, Int32 rowIndex)
>   at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.OnCellValueChanged(DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
>   at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.OnCellValueChangedInternal(DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
>   at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCell.SetValue(Int32 rowIndex, Object value)
>   at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCell.set_Value(Object value)

Fisrt time exception occurs, Count was:
RowIndex = 0 : RowCount = 1; ColumnCount = 9 ; P_Count 15

I tryed it again: 
RowIndex = 0 : RowCount = 1; ColumnCount = 9 ; P_Count 93

Again it was: 
RowIndex = 0 : RowCount = 1; ColumnCount = 9 ; P_Count 7

If I delete complete row & reinsert with updated value.. In that case there is no exception.. But I want to edit that particular cell.. & I think that deleting & reinserting row is not a proper way.. It's time consuming..

Please suggest solution.

Comment: how many columns does your datagridview have?

Comment: It seems your datargid has less than 3 columns. Take in consideration that index is zero based

Comment: 9 columns.. & its throwing exception randomly.. Not every time..

Comment: did you tried to debug the code and check the `Cells.Count` value ? especially in the case where the exception is thrown?

Comment: If I delete complete row & reinsert with updated value.. In that case there is no exception.. But I want to edit that particular cell.. & I think that deleting & reinserting row is not a proper way.. It's time consuming..

Comment: can you post a screenshot of your `DataGridView` ? can you add manually rows by clicking on the view? if so then it might be that the last row is simply an empty entry which has no columns and crashes your code

Comment: Cells.Count is 9

Comment: need more information to solve this one. What do you do before the loop?

Comment: No.. rows are not editable by users... We cannot add rows manually.

Comment: Its a separate function.. I am just iterating rows in it... There is nothing before loop

Comment: Are you calling this from some `DataGridView` event handler?

Comment: No.. Not calling by DataGridView Event handler..

Comment: Why would the last line of the trace say _at System.Windows.Forms.PropertyStore.GetObject(Int32 key, Boolean& found) at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellStyle. **set_SelectionBackColor(Color value)**_ ???

Comment: where does the value for f_colcount comes from ? Can you show us ? Might this be a value different than you expect ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like this to find out where your error comes from ?
After you have found and fixed the error you can remove the try catch

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGrdVwReport.Rows)
{
   try
   {
       row.Cells[2].Value = p_Count;  //Exception here
   }
   catch (exception ex)
   {
       // write code here to log the rowcount, columncount, p_count, and other stuff here
       throw;
   }
}
```

Comment: Yes I have added code in try catch block already.. So that I have shown exception & Stacktrace.. & exception is not for specific row.. It's very random..

Comment: and what was the columncount ? and the rowcount ?

Comment: Fisrt time exception occurs, Count was:
RowIndex = 0 : RowCount = 1; ColumnCount = 9 ; P_Count 15
I tryed it again:
RowIndex = 0 : RowCount = 1; ColumnCount = 9 ; P_Count 93
Again it was:
RowIndex = 0 : RowCount = 1; ColumnCount = 9 ; P_Count 7

Comment: It would be better if you edited your question and put this information it it. It is relevant info and you can make it more readable there

Comment: can you show the code you used in your catch that gave you these results ?